# Format a decimal with currency symbol and no trailing zeroes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cultureinfo, asp.net-4.5

The current culture is "fr-FR" (already set in the application)

```
decimal amount = 20m;

var formattedCurrency = string.Format(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, "{0:C}", amount);
```

It gives me `20,00 €`

***how to remove the trailing zeroes?***

1. Note: If the amount is 20.01, then the output should be 20,01 €
2. If the amount is 20.00, then the output should be 20 €

EDIT:

I tried using `G29` to remove trailing zeroes, but lost the currency symbol. :(

Comment: @DanielCook but `20.01` will be `20` not `20.01`

Comment: @DanielCook: Yes, it rounds it off. I dont want the number to be rounded-off, but just wanna remove trailing zeroes from it.

Comment: nope, {0:C0} not works  https://dotnetfiddle.net/F3cJmu

Comment: Do you want 20,1 € for 20.1?

Comment: @DanielCook: Yes. Exactly. No rounding off but keep the currency symbol.

Comment: if you have time then check my code/fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
string.Format(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, "{0:#.##}", amount) + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol
```

If you need to know where the currency symbol should appear, it becomes a bit more complex, but this could be sufficient (depending on your situation).

The thing is, you can't specify conditional digits for a currency format and there are good reasons you shouldn't!

The thing is: `20` loses significant digits over `20.00`, so the customer doesn't know whether it's `20.01` rounded down or `20.00` rounded down. I would use `{0:C}` unless I have a very good reason not to.

Comment: Good answer. But, the currency symbol may be placed before or after the amount value depending upon the culture. Eg. `$20` for `US` but the same is `€20` in `FR`

Comment: Exactly what my comment on my answer was intend to

Comment: You can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern.aspx for Currency Symbol placement, but I wanted to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
double dec = 20.01;

string amount = string.Format("{0:#.##}", dec);
switch (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern)
   {
         case 0:
            amount = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol + amount;
                    break;
         case 1:
            amount = amount + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;
                    break;
         case 2:
            amount =  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol + " " + amount;
                    break;
         case 3:
            amount = amount + " " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;
                    break;
}
```

Updated after Davio's comment

Regards.

Comment: Please read my question fully. I want to print a decimal to a string with the currency symbol but no trailing zeroes

Comment: dummy question but will you always use the same currency ?

Comment: @Aymeric the dot is actually the "localized decimal separator"; if your locale uses , for it's decimal separator, "." will print that.

Comment: How about negative values? There is a currency pattern for that as well! The main issue is: look at how ugly this code becomes when you want to emulate everything that a simple `{0:C}` does, only because you wan't to chop off some zeroes.

Comment: Sure it complexifies compare to a `{0:C}`. Regarding the NegativePattern you can handle it the same way

Answer (score 1):

try this one  https://dotnetfiddle.net/F3cJmu

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{
    double amount = 39.5555;

    string decimalPoint = (amount).ToString();

    decimalPoint = decimalPoint.Substring(decimalPoint.IndexOf(".") + 1);

    if( decimalPoint.Length > 0)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"),"{0:C" + decimalPoint.Length +"}", amount));
    else
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"),"{0:C}", amount));

}
}
```

Comment: But, if amount is `39.00` it produces `30.0 €`. It should just be `30 €`

Comment: Hey, check out my updated solution. this solution solved currency symbol placement problem

Comment: Seems fine. Thank you :)